# Modify Wordpress get_image_tag output?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-lazyload

According to [jQuery.lazyload](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) any images I'd like to "lazyload" need to have the `src` attribute replaced with `data-original`.

I'm assuming I can do this using WordPress [get_image_tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_image_tag) filter, but I'm stuck on how to actually make it happen.

```
function image_src( $id, $alt, $title, $align, $size ) {
    $html = '<img data-orginial="' . esc_attr($img_src) . '"/>';
    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'get_image_tag', 'image_src', 10, 5 );
```

For lazyload to work a `lazy` class also needs to be placed on the IMG, which I managed to get working using WordPress [get_image_tag_class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/get_image_tag_class) filter

```
function image_class( $classes ) {
    return $classes . ' lazy';
}
add_filter( 'get_image_tag_class', 'image_class' );
```

Any thoughts on how I can change the IMG output to replace `data-orginial` instead of `src`?

Answer (score 1):

Rich-

I ran into the same problem and went down the same path as you, trying to use `get_image_tag` with poor results. So I came up with a JS workaround - the code comments should show you how to get this working:

```
function() {
  // To get lazy loading working on blog post
  // 1- Assign all image source paths into a sourcePath variable
  var sourcePath = $("figure").find("img").attr("src");

  // 2- Nullify source paths, move path to data-original attribute and add lazy-load class to img
  $("figure").find("img").attr({
    "src" : " ",
    "data-original" : sourcePath
  }).addClass("lazy-load");

  // 3- Applies lazy-loading jQuery plugin to image elements
  $("img.lazy-load").lazyload({
    effect : "fadeIn"
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to replace the `src` part

```
function image_src( $id, $alt, $title, $align, $size ) {
  if( ! is_admin() ) $html = str_replace("img src=","img data-original=",$html);
  return $html;
}
add_filter( 'get_image_tag', 'image_src', 10, 5 );
```

You may have to adjust it to make it match the original `<img>` settings.

Edit: added Nath's suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It looks like this will break adding images in the WordPress editor. And I'm thinking there might not be a way around that.

Comment: @rich you might be able to add a `if (!is_admin()) { ... }` which should stop it happening inside the admin panel.

Comment: @ɴᴀᴛʜ Good thought. That's probably on the right track, although it doesn't seem to work immediately.

Comment: I guess it doesn't specifically say to remove the src but none of the examples seem to have it. It's my understanding that data-originial acts as a placeholder for src. So when the image comes into view the src is applied, which the DOM then loads. Maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: No you are probably right. It makes sense. There is another way to change it. After page load use javascript/jQuery. And you could always ask the developer. You can't be the first one to use it like this.